# VSIXInstaller showing error message and not installing .VSIX files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I am trying to install the SQLite SDK for building Windows 8.1 desktop and mobile Application.
The issue i faced is that when i downloaded the SDK it was with .VSIX extension.
 
I have tried opening it by:
1.Double clicking directly.
2.With Visual Studio Selector.
3.Developer Command Prompt ( both normal and elevator command ).
4.Running the VSIXInstaller.exe as an administrator from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

Nothing happens. It is not installing. 
But when i open the VSIXInstaller.exe with administrator, it is showing me this ( the image is shown below ).

[image: VSIXInstaller.exe_image]

I am running Windows 10 Pro with Visual Studio 2015 Pro.

Comment: Unblock the VSIX file?

Comment: Its not blocked. What i can make of this is that VSIXInstaller is installed. But the SDK of the extension .vsix is not installing which i cannot understand the reason why is this so. @ErikEJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

Go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates

Look for SQL Lite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) and SQL Lite for Windows Phone 8.1 and download them

[SQL Lite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) and SQL Lite for Windows Phone 8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoZxv.png)

Then it appears in your Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Installed -> SDKs, means you have got your SQL Lite SDK

I do not know why it installed this way, and not getting installed via https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. [VSIXInstaller from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574829/how-to-install-visual-studio-gallery-extensions-from-command-line)

Command:
VSIXInstaller.exe /a "absolutepath\some_extension.vsix"

Comment: I tried using the link you provided. I had no luck. I answered my question. Thank you.