# Install Visual Studio extension (.vsix) in Azure Pipelines (CI)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-extensions

I need to install the Visual Studio extension `InstallerProjects.vsix` in the Azure Piplines to build my `.vdproj`. But I can't find anything about how to install it.

I tried the following `azure-pipelines.yml` configuration without success:

```
stages:
  - stage: Foo
    jobs:
      - job: 'Bar'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-2019'
          demands:
            - msbuild
            - visualstudio
        steps:
          - script: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" InstallerProjects.vsix'
          - task: VSBuild@1
            inputs:
              solution: ./MyProject.vdproj
```

Am I able to install extensions in the Pipeline and if yes how?

Thx in advance!

Comment: You need to tell the agent where to download that .vsix file. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: I have the file in the repo

Comment: Then check the agent log and see what's written there. You should always try to use a custom agent to iron out issues, and then switch to Microsoft's agent.

Comment: I'm not able to configure that. But the microsoft Agent takes infinite time to run the `script` step

Comment: You probably forgot /q, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Mar/01/Registering-and-Unregistering-a-VSIX-Extension-from-the-Command-Line

Comment: At first yes but later I tried `/admin` and `/quite` and nothing worked

Comment: @Lukas Kirner Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue , according to previous [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908015/how-to-build-visual-studio-installer-project-in-azure-devops-pipeline-hosted-age), it is not feasible to install `InstallerProjects.vsix` extension from the command line in azure devops. If you open the command line as an administrator and execute the installation command locally, it will be successful, but not in azure devops, because we cannot execute the command line as an administrator in the command line task .

AFAIK , building a Visual Studio Installer project in the Azure Devops Pipeline hosted agent is not supported at this moment. As a workaround , you have to [configure your own build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) to run the build. Make sure the VS Installer Projects extension is installed on private agent and then you can build the setup project either use command line task with "devenv" or use the "Build VS Installer" task. You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570869/vsts-online-building-setup-projects) for details.

In addition , there is an open [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/382210/add-support-to-build-installer-project-vdproj-in-a.html) in Developer Community about this. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there. A contributor in this uservoice proposed a solution using third-party extensions, you can also refer to it.

Comment: So am I not able to install any VS Extension inside the Microsoft Agent? Thats wired

Comment: At present, VS Installer extension looks like this.